# Avoid Inheritance JsonConverter Recursion

Tags: c#, json

So I've got an API that I hit in order to get details about animals in a database

The animals have IDs so my web request looks like so `/animal/1234`

The response from the API looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "Tony",
  "type": "Tiger",
  "stripeCount": 14
}
```

Or alternatively

```
{
  "name": "Kermit",
  "type": "Frog",
  "slimy": true
}
```

When I query the API I don't know what `type` of animal I'll get back, but in some cases I would like to deserialise them into classes appropriate to their `type`

Here's the classes I'm working with at the moment, complete with the `JsonConverter` attribute I'm trying to use:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(AnimalJsonConverter))]
class Animal {
  public string name { get; set; }
  public string type { get; set; }
}

class Tiger : Animal {
  public int stripeCount { get; set; }
}
```

I've set up a `JsonConverter<Animal>` which implements the method `ReadJson` like so:

```
public override Animal ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Post existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
  var animalObj = JObject.Load(reader);
  var type = (string)animalObj["type"];

  switch(type) {
    case "Tiger":
      return animalObj.ToObject<Tiger>();
    default:
      return animalObj.ToObject<Animal>();
  }
}
```

This leads to a problem however as the statement `animalObj.ToObject<Tiger>();` respects the `JsonConverter` on `Animal` and attempts to call my `ReadJson` method again, causing recursion hell

If anyone can see a solution to this problem I would be much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a different tactic - populating an instance of the type:

```cs
class AnimalJsonConverter : JsonConverter<Animal>
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Animal value, 
                                  JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override Animal ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, 
              Animal existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var animalObj = JObject.Load(reader);
        var type = (string)animalObj["type"];

        Animal instance;

        switch (type)
        {
            case "Tiger":
                instance = new Tiger();
                break;

            case "Frog":
                instance = new Frog();
                break;

            default:
                instance = new Animal();
                break;
        }

        serializer.Populate(animalObj.CreateReader(), instance);
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tested your solution and it works fine, so +1. But why not to put some exception in `WriteJson`? Something like `NotImplemented` or `NotSupported`?  Your converter may confuse new users if they decide to use it to serialize object.